# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'method'

Tags: python, function, methods, trading

I'm trying to run this function to backtest a daily pivot strategy. Looks like the error is on under #pivor point, tried changing these to float but can't since it's saved as a series. Not really sure how else to troubleshoot.

```
def pivot_trading_performance(ticker):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    stock = ticker.history(start = "2018-09-15", end = "2021-11-01")

    # pivot point
    stock['pivot'] = (stock.High.shift(1) + stock.Low.shift(1) + stock.Close.shift(1)) / 3

    # ENTRY RULE

    # Enter long position if the stock price of the stock > pivot point
    stock['long_entry'] = stock.Close > stock.pivot

    # EXIT RULE
    # Exit position if stock price < pivot point

    stock['long_exit']= stock.Close < stock.pivot

    # POSITIONS
    # Long postitions = 1
    # No position = 0

    stock['positions_long']= np.nan
    stock.loc[stock.long_entry, 'positions_long'] = 1
    stock.loc[stock.long_exit, 'positions_long'] = 0

    stock['Signal'] = stock.positions_long

    stock = stock.fillna(method = 'ffill')

    ## STRATEGY RETURNS
    # Compute log returns of the stock & multiply by signal 1,-1,0 to get the strategy returns
    daily_log_returns = np.log(stock.Close/stock.Close.shift(1))
    daily_log_returns = daily_log_returns * stock.Signal.shift(1)

    return daily_returns
```

Answer (score 0):

because pivot is a method of the dataframe, either change the name of the column to avoid headaches or use `stock["pivot"]` instead of `stock.pivot` when trying to access the data in that column