# Data types when plotting a hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 2D histogram using 2 columns in a dataframe (here's a snippet of the data here :

```
            relevance   ratio   mean
0   0.635266925998546   0.48717948717948717 2.8293641135319985
1   0.8024759680807747  0.5977011494252874  4.769829806901302
2   0.7938352843184088  0.6265060240963856  5.063955003405357
3   0.8270877609099303  0.41935483870967744 12.29401084132898
4   0.7695503203351798  0.44776119402985076 8.510369905054274
5   0.8513853897448349  0.28695652173913044 13.169903248451313
6   0.8544935485775926  0.12658227848101267 12.063579823506643
7   0.8395833284774789  0.19047619047619047 9.372998776898859
8   0.8796642155254841  0.16883116883116883 9.218498721423206
9   0.7414921294548873  0.0 8.658189626458995
10  0.5463891924615218  0.07575757575757576 3.3982228628036566
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist2d(data.mean, data.relevance,bins=5, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

However I do get the following error :

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'method'
```

Does anyone know the possible cause? I did check if all values were of the same type.

Thank you!

Comment: [`DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) is a method, so here you need bracket notation to reference the column: `data['mean']`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074840/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-method